# Reading Korean through a CSV in Python

Tags: python

I am having an issue reading a CSV file in to Python containing English and Korean Characters, have tested my code without the Korean and it works fine.

Code (Python - 3.6.4)

```
import csv
with open('Kor3.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
print(your_list)
```

Error

> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position
>   2176: character maps to undefined

CSV File Output: This has been converted from Excel to unicode text then filename changed to CSV. Think this is the route of the problem. 
Would it be better to read from an Excel or another format?

Sample Input (2 Columns)

생일 축하해요     Happy birthday

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x there is a drop-in replacement for the built-in `csv` module with support for Unicode: [`unicodecsv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the encoding when opening the file:

```
with open('Kor3.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python 3. Csv functions will read with unicode by default

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I was having was the Korean was being converted to question marks when converting from Excel to CSV hence the Unicode text encoding,

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just went with importing from the excel file think this was an issue with the csv rather than python. Thanks for your help.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('Korean.xlsx')
values = []
for s in wb.sheets():
    #print 'Sheet:',s.name
    for row in range(1, s.nrows):
        col_names = s.row(0)
        col_value = []
        for name, col in zip(col_names, range(s.ncols)):
            value  = (s.cell(row,col).value)
            try : value = str(int(value))
            except : pass
            col_value.append((value))
        values.append(col_value)
print(values) #test
print(values[0][1],values[1][1]) #test2
```